# Lost outputs from RMD file in Rstudio

Tags: r, r-markdown, rstudio

The problem is rather simple, however I cannot find any solution online.
Working with RStudio on a giant Rmd file and all of sudden I lost the output from all my code chunks. Running all the code again will take days.

I can see that some sort of temp data are stored in the folder `.Rproj.user`. Does anyone know how to recover the outputs? Global environment is fine.

Thank you!

Comment: You'll need to be more specific. Did you use the RMD files to save outputs onto disk and they are lost/deleted?

Comment: No. Simply I was used to see the code output below each chunk, then suddenly all the figures, tables, etc disappeared. All the outputs were cleared, but the objects were still in the environment.

I'm wondering if there is a way to recover the plots or alternatively to save them on disk (without knitting an entire new report), to avoid the same problem in the future.

Comment: There are a variety of ways to save any kind of object to disk out of R. `saveRDS()` will save any object. `ggsave()` will save an image of a `ggplot2` chart. `write.csv()` will save data frames. There are many other options as well.

Comment: Otherwise, just executing the name of an object in the console will display that object. How it gets displayed depends on the object. A data frame will be displayed in the console, while a ggplot2 chart object will get displayed in the Plots pane of your Rstudio IDE.